# Scrape parameters in the onclick function using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to scrape a website using python but I'm not able to scrape the parameters in the onclick function.
HTML is as follows

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="tabsborder2">
    <tbody><tr class="cleft-link1" height="20">
      <td width="3%">S/N</td>
       <td width="20%">Generic / Quantity</td>
       <td width="3%">Type</td>
      <td width="10%">Package Unit</td>
      <td width="9%">Price(In Rs.)</td>
      <td width="9%">Available Brands</td>
      </tr>
    
      
     <tr class="row">
      <td height="20" valign="top" class="mosttext">1</td>
      <td valign="top" class="mosttext">Aminophylline : 225 mg</td>
      <td height="20" valign="top" class="mosttext">
      Tablet </td> 
       
      <td height="20" valign="top" class="mosttext">10 Tablet</td>
      <td height="20" valign="top" class="mosttext">5.09</td>
      
      
      <td height="20" valign="top" class="mosttext">


       
                    
      <a href="#" onclick="MM_openBrWindow(&#39;searching_list_brands_npp.php?qty=959@225 mg&amp;gcount=1&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=600&#39;)"><img src="./__Welcome to Medguideindia.com____ Your Ultimate Medicine Guide_files/brand_icon.GIF" border="0"></a>
              
      </td>  
                
      
          
    </tr>
      
     <tr class="row">
      <td height="20" valign="top" class="mosttext">2</td>
      <td valign="top" class="mosttext">Vit E : 100 mg</td>
      <td height="20" valign="top" class="mosttext">
      Capsule </td> 
       
      <td height="20" valign="top" class="mosttext">10 Capsule</td>
      <td height="20" valign="top" class="mosttext">5.34</td>
      
      
      <td height="20" valign="top" class="mosttext">


                    <a href="#" onclick="MM_openBrWindow(&#39;searching_list_similar_brands.php?similarpid=131,259,315,666,944,1004,2955&amp;qty=131@100 mg&amp;gcount=1&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=600&#39;)"><img src="./__Welcome to Medguideindia.com____ Your Ultimate Medicine Guide_files/brand_icon.GIF" border="0"></a>   
                               
          
      </td>
```

I was able to scrape the text in the td tag but they are not organised either.
Code:

```
    
    page = requests.get(baseurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html5lib')
    table = soup.find('table', attrs = {'class':'tabsborder2'})

    for row in table.find_all('tr', attrs = {'class':'row'}):
        m= {}
        names = soup.find_all('td', attrs = {'class':'mosttext'})
        for name in names:
            text = name.text
            m['Data'] = text
            
            response= Selector(text=names)
            link_id = response.xpath('//td/a[contains(@onclick, "MM_openBrWindow")]/@onclick').re_first( r'"([^"]+)"')

            df = df.append(m, ignore_index=True)
```

Issue 1(important)- How do I scrape the 1st parameters in the onclick function?
Issue 2- I want to scrape the content and append them to a dataframe so that I can save it as a .csv file. But the text is getting appended to dataframe in different lines. I tried adding them to rows but it didn't work.

Can someone suggest a way to solve it? Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse the parameters from the `onclick=` parameter you can use next example (`html_doc` is HTML snippet from your question):

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select("[onclick]"):
    onclick_url = re.search(r"'(.*?)'", tag["onclick"]).group(1)
    p = parse_qs(urlparse(onclick_url).query)
    print(p)
```

Prints:

```py
{'qty': ['959@225 mg'], 'gcount': ['1']}
{'similarpid': ['131,259,315,666,944,1004,2955'], 'qty': ['131@100 mg'], 'gcount': ['1']}
```